# superagent: is a file exist?

Tags: javascript, superagent

with the code below I can start downloading file:

```
var stream = fs.createWriteStream('file.zip');

request.get('http://example.com/file.zip').pipe(stream);
```

how can I check that file exist with superagent without downloading it?

Comment: There is no such thing as "file" in HTTP, but you can use `HTTP HEAD` to ensure it returns `HTTP 200` back: https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#head-requests

Comment: Thanks. it works. feel free to create the answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Just post it yourself so that it was searchable for others :-)